# Upgradation issue from Struts 1.1 to Struts 1.2.4

Tags: struts, struts-1

We have a legacy application in struts 1.1.
While trying to update from struts 1.1 to struts 1.2.4 for this legacy application after updating the struts jar we are facingg issue with `org.apache.struts.tiles.ActionComponentServlet`.

The error is :

> > The import org.apache.struts.tiles.ActionComponentServlet cannot be resolved

As struts 1.2.4 do not have `org.apache.struts.tiles.ActionComponentServlet` it produces a compilation issue. What will be the way out?

Comment: If that's the old way of wrapping up an action to be a Tiles component, maybe it's `org.apache.struts.tiles.ActionController`? I haven't thought about S1.1 for a decade. Why upgrade to 1.2.4?!

Comment: As this is a legacy application we can not straight way update to latest struts jar due to huge amount of work. we are planning for progressive update to struts 1.2.4 to address the security issues in struts 1.1 which got fixed in struts 1.2.4